# Compiling litecoind on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: litecoin, currencies, compiling

I am trying to compile litecoind on Ubuntu 15.04 and I stuck here:

```
/litecoin/src$ make -f makefile.unix USE_UPNP=-
make: makefile.unix: No such file or directory 
make: *** No rule to make target 'makefile.unix'.  Stop.
```

I found some a little bit different ways to compile litecoind, but every time I have problems with "makefile.unix". Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

The build system has changed to `autotools` in later versions of Litecoin.

The process now looks like this:

```
./autogen.sh 
./configure
make -j4 
make install # optional
```

There's up to date instructions in detail in [build-unix.md](https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin/blob/master-0.10/doc/build-unix.md).

Comment: What difference does it make if I don't do `make install` ? Why is it optional?

Comment: You might not want the binaries to be anywhere but the build directory.

Comment: is that a reply for my comment above?

Comment: Yes. You don’t need to make install because that moves the binaries, which you might not want.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be on your unix src dir where the file located
and then open the src dir with the terminal and then

```
./autogen.sh 
./configure
make -j4 
make install # optional
```